# clear form after submission

Tags: php, javascript, forms, search, onsubmit

when I submit the form below, it search works the first time, but if I try another search, it gives me the same answer, example:
First I search "operat"---> it returns for example "operational suffix"
Then if I search "flight" ---> it returns "operational suffix" again
Below you will find the code, Thank you in advance!

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" class="form-inline" method="GET" action="index.php">
<select name="select">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>    
<option value="Data Element Name">Data Element Name</option>    
<option value="Term">Term</option>    
<option value="Diagram">Diagram</option>  
</select>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
<input type="submit" class="btn">
</form>
<table id="resultTable"></table> 

<?php
function connection(){
/*****************************************************************************/
//Get values from the form
$search = $_GET['search'];
$select = $_GET['select'];
/*****************************************************************************/
//Define needed values to log in
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbusername='username';
$dbuserpass='pass';
$dbname = 'db_name';
/*****************************************************************************/
// connect to the mysql database server
$connection=mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpass);
/*****************************************************************************/
//select the database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Cannot select database');
/*****************************************************************************/
//Create the Query
$result="SELECT name from tbl_name WHERE stereotype LIKE 'Term' AND name LIKE '%$search%' ";
/*****************************************************************************/
//Sending the request
$req =mysql_query($result,$connection);
if (!$req )
{
die(mysql_error());
}
/*****************************************************************************/
//Loop to stock results on an array 
$array=array();
$i=0;
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
{ 
$array[$i]=$data['name'];
$i=$i+1;
}
/*****************************************************************************/
//return the result to javascript
return json_encode($array);
/*****************************************************************************/
}
?>
<script>
$('#form1').submit(function() {  
$('#resultTable').empty();
alert(document.forms["form1"]["search"].value);
if (document.forms["form1"]["select"].value=="Term" ){
var tab=<?php echo connection();?>;
for(i=0;i<tab.length;i++) {$('#resultTable').append('<tr><td>'+tab[i]+'</td></tr>');}
}
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: what values you are getting in these variables $_GET['search'],$_GET['select'] for every search request?

Comment: in your javascript try to log your query : `console.log($result);`
or var_dump your `$data` and see what are the results.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the html and php are in the wrong order. Normal flow:

1. Set variables
2. Create db connection
3. Insert / update stuff in db
4. Select stuff from db
5. Display stuff

In your case, the stuff is inserted after your form is rendered

If it's not your case, try checking if you use javascript or offline storage stuff.

Comment: Thanks for responding! In my case, when the form is submitted, JS is called (`$('#form1').submit(function() {..}`), and in the script, I take the result of the php file (`var tab=<?php echo connection();?>;`) I don't insert/update anything in the db, but just consult, and the php is ordred as you said.